# Deal with window state in MdiArea

Tags: qt

I use in my app a MDI central widget. Currently I always open a child as maximized

```
child->showMaximized();
```

This cause problems if I use cascaded or tiled workspace. 
Now I tried to find out if the subwindows are maximized or not. If not I want to open them in

```
child->showNormal();
```

But the snippet:

```
    foreach(QWidget* widget, mdiArea->subWindowList()) {
        if(widget->windowState()==Qt::WindowMaximized){
            qDebug("maximized");
        }else{
            qDebug("not maximized");
        }
    }
```

It looks that this subwindow will only have WindowActive and WindowNoState. 
Any idea how to check if the subwindow (child) is maximized or not?

With maximized I talk about the full mdiArea (Workspace)

Comment: change to `if(widget->windowState() & Qt::WindowMaximized)` and provide a [MRE]

Comment: many thanks, this works well.

Comment: I will post an answer explaining your problem, I hope you mark it as correct

Answer (score 0):

windowState() returns a set of flags, so for example windowState() can indicate that a window is active (Qt::WindowActive) and maximized (Qt::WindowMaximized), so if you want to verify if one of them is active you must use the operator "&":

```cpp
if(widget->windowState() & Qt::WindowMaximized)
```